# Disjoint cycle Decomposition.

Tags: permutations

Let $\sigma =(a_1...a_6)$ be a $6$-cycle. Write the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^3$.

I know that $a_1*a_1=\epsilon $ but does this mean that $\sigma^2=\epsilon$  and then $\sigma^2=\sigma$ ?

Comment: How do you know that $a_1*a_2=\epsilon$? What does that even mean? What is $a_1$ and what does $*$ mean?

Comment: Have you tried actually writing out $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^3$?

Comment: I've tried to write it out, I'm not sure if I'm multiplying? in the write way though.

Comment: Do it first for $\sigma=(123456)$.

Comment: would that mean σ2=(135)(246) (sorry about the notation! I'm new and not good with that stuff yet)